# Delete, Edit, and Save Row Function on Dynamic HTML Table

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, dynamic

I have an HTML table that imports data from a database. Currently, I have 4 buttons at the bottom. Add Row, Edit, Save, and Delete. I have the "Add Row" button working and functioning correctly. So my question is a two part question...

First, how can I get the delete function working?

Secondly, how can I get the edit and save function to start working as well?

HTML/PHP Code:

```
<table id="html_master">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>MR_ID</td>
    <td>MR_Name</td>
    <td>Buyer_ID</td>
    <td>MR_POC_N</td>
    <td>MR_POC_E</td>
    <td>MR_POC_P</td>
    <td>Select</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td id="mr_id"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td id="mr_name"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td id="buyer_id"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td id="poc_n"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td id="poc_e"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td id="poc_p"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="checked"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>
</table>

        <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="insRow('html_master')">
        <input type="button" id="edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="button" id="save" value="Save"> 
        <input type="button" id="delRow" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow('html_master')">
```

Javascript Code:

```
// ----- Deletes row -----
function deleteRow(tableID) {
    try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
    }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}

// ----- Add Row -----

function insRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element3.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell4.appendChild(element4);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var element5 = document.createElement("input");
    element5.type = "text";
    element5.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell5.appendChild(element5);

    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var element6 = document.createElement("input");
    element6.type = "text";
    element6.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell6.appendChild(element6);

    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    var element7 = document.createElement("input");
    element7.type = "checkbox";
    element7.name="chkbox[]";
    cell7.appendChild(element7);

    }
```

Comment: This looks to be database-related. Once you get the DELETE part going, UPDATE syntax will be similar.

Comment: Yes, it is database-related.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Are you having difficulty with the front end JavaScript? Or the PHP backend? To delete for instance would require some javascript on the front end to determine the rows to be deleted which you seem to have but then a call to the backend to perform the actual delete with PHP. Are you using AJAX? Or do you want to reload the entire page? Try breaking down the steps and tackle them one at a time. Much easier to help that way.

Comment: I am not using AJAX and I do not want to reload the page. However, I have another page unrelated to this where I can add/delete rows and am not using AJAX...so do i need to use it? I am also having trouble with the Javascript...i don't think the PHP is the problem.

Comment: there appear to be spurious closing table cell tags ( `</td>` ) after each of the buttons

Comment: Oops, I fixed that and updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a quick mock-up test the following works ok and deletes the rows where a checkbox is checked.

By using `querySelectorAll` you can be quite specific with what you are trying to find - in the code below notice that it is looking for all `input` elements of type `checkbox` that are currently `checked` - once you have that nodelist it is easy to iterate through and perform whatever action(s) you need - in this case remove it's parent row.

```
function deleteRow(id){
    var tbl=document.getElementById(id);
    var col=tbl.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    if( col ){
        for( var n in col )if( col[ n ].nodeType==1 ){
            try {
                var tr=col[ n ].parentNode.parentNode;
                var tbody=tr.parentNode;
                tbody.removeChild( tr );
            }catch( err ){
                console.warn(err);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a function available like the following:

```
function createNode( type, attribs, parent ) {
    /*
        @type - the html element type you wish to add. By default if you use 'null' as the value it will insert a div
        @attribs - Object literal of param:value pairs to add as attributes to the new html node
        @parent - the parent html element to which the new node will be added.

        This returns the new node. The parent can also be another call to `createNode`
    */
    try{
        var el = ( typeof( type )=='undefined' || type==null ) ? document.createElement( 'div' ) : document.createElement( type );
        for( var n in attribs ) if( attribs.hasOwnProperty( n ) && n!=='innerHTML' ) el.setAttribute( n, attribs[ n ] );
        if( attribs.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML') ) el.innerHTML=attribs.innerHTML;
        if( parent!=null ) typeof( parent )=='object' ? parent.appendChild( el ) : document.getElementById( parent ).appendChild( el );
        return el;

    }catch(err){
        console.warn('createNode: %s, %o, %o',type, attribs, parent);
    }
}
```

Then you can simplify the `insRow` function like:

```
function insRow(id){

    var tbl=document.getElementById( id );
    var tbody = tbl.querySelectorAll('tbody')[0];
    var rows = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');

    var row = createNode( 'tr',{},tbody );
    var td = createNode('td',{ innerHTML:rows.length },row );

    /* add 5 table cells with textfields */
    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ ){
        createNode('input',{ type:'text',name:'txtbox[]'},createNode('td',{},row ) );
    }
    /* Add table cell with checkbox */
    createNode('input',{ type:'checkbox',name:'chkbox[]'},createNode('td',{},row ) );
}
```

Just thought I'd add that in there as it's been a hard day at work so a little light coding helped me unwind - hope you'll find that `createNode` function useful.

Comment: In the `function deleteRow(id) {` would the `(id)` be the id of my table?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to figure it out...the delete function now works great! Thank you!

Comment: Would the edit and save button functions be similar to this somehow?

Comment: You could use much of the same code but it really depends upon what the functionality required is - if you are saving to/updating a database then ajax is the way forward.

Comment: Yes, I would like it to save/update to a DB so I guess AJAX is the way then.